# Add middlewares on all mutations using Hot Chocolate v11

Tags: entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

I'm working on Transaction per mutation with EF core. I tried an implementation by adding my transaction logic into the Request pipeline `UseRequest` and it's quite good. But the problem with this implementation is that the transaction logic will be executed each time we have an incoming request Query or Mutation.
I think that the Hot Chocolate middlewares can do the work by adding a middleware on all incoming mutations, but the only doc I found is about adding middlewares to fields https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-workshop/blob/master/docs/5-understanding-middleware.md.
Is there a way to add middlewares on all mutations? thanks.

Comment: Your feature request has been heared and here is the pull request, that will deliver the requested functionality:
https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/pull/2913
It will be merged as soon as docs and testing are done. Until then you could habe a look at the code of the PR to see how it was done.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a loot at the PR code. waiting for the release to use this new feature :D